# Extract a particular version file from Git repository

Tags: git, msysgit

Is it possible to pull out a specific version of a file from a Git repository to an external folder location?

I have a few excel (binary) files in y Git repo. I want to pull out specific version of that file to an external folder without having to do a `git checkout`, so that my current working directory is not disturbed.

```
System information:
Windows 8, 64 bit.
msysgit 1.9.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an useful tool on git. It can be use by `show` command.
See all of the options of **show** by giving command -

```
git show
```

If you want to see the particular version of a file just use the following format -

```
git show commit:filename
```

Now export to a file by --

```
git show commit:filename > newfilename
```

Comment: I am hoping in future versions this can be accomplished from the Git UI itself. For now this will work.

Answer (score 2):

`git show <commit>:<path>` will print out file in given path from given commit. Just store it into a file using `>` and you're done.

Comment: yes, this looks like a nifty trick. I tried it and worked just fine. But I think there would be a simpler way to do it from Git Gui. I up-voted your answer, but waiting for a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it'll work for binary files. You can use the `git show` command. The usage will be:

```
git show commitHash:path/to/file.xls
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that show will only show the file in the console. For a binary file it will not help. And anyway what I am trying to do here is to extract a copy of the file of a specific version to an external directory.

Comment: Use output redirection as mentioned in the solution by che to put the output to a file `git show commitHash:path/to/file.xls > file.xls`